# android - alert dialog builder confirmation button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my app I have used an alert dialog builder for button click. So when I press a button, little pop up is opened with options - Activate and Deactivate. So can i make that when a user press Activate or Deactivate, Confirmation widnows open with question are you sure ? and a choice yes or no ??

Comment: why couldn't you ? What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created dialog inside another dialog.

See this code:

```
twsbiSelectionMenuDialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
            twsbiSelectionMenuDialog.setContentView(R.layout.twsbi_selection_menu_dialog);
            twsbiSelectionMenuDialog.setCancelable(true);
            twsbiSelectionMenuDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            
            // To Open new Canvas ===================================
            Button newLayoutButton = (Button) twsbiSelectionMenuDialog.findViewById(R.id.newLayoutButton);
            newLayoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    twsbiSelectionMenuDialog.dismiss();
                    // AlertDialog for confirmation
                    AlertDialog.Builder clearConfirmDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TWSBIDrawMainActivity.this);
                    clearConfirmDialog.setMessage("Do you want to clear this and open new canvas ?").setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // Action for 'Yes' Button
                            myView = new MyView(TWSBIDrawMainActivity.this);
                            takePhotoFromCamera = false;
                            takePhotoFromGallery = false;
                            canvasColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;
                            drawingLayout.removeView(myView);
                            drawingLayout.addView(myView);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //  Action for 'NO' Button
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = clearConfirmDialog.create();
                    alert.setTitle("Draw");
                    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
                    alert.show();
                }
            });
            
            // For canvas Color Selection ===================================
            Button canvasColorButton = (Button) twsbiSelectionMenuDialog.findViewById(R.id.canvasColorButton);
            canvasColorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    twsbiSelectionMenuDialog.dismiss();
                    pickColour(); // to pick colour
                }
            });
```

Just refer that for your condition and it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog. popup this dialog after user press Activate or Deactivate Button.

Answer (score 0):

The windows technique. Yes this is possible, just popup another dialog, after that one.