# How to show dialog popup on confirmation popup?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have dialog popup. There is a button in it. When I click the button, the confirmation popup(Yes/No) will be shown. But the problem is that the dialog popup closed. I don't want to close dialog popup when the confirmation popup show. I would like to know how to do it. here my coding..

```
    Button deleteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose delete tasks");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()   {               
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            showMsgDialog();
        }
    });

    private void showMsgDialog() {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("deleting..");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure want to delete?");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  // deleting process.
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: Have you actually Googled? I can actually find a few answers on SO in first google attempt.

Comment: I got it from this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/9126143/1156041

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't want to close dialog popup when the confirmation popup show.
```

### Its not Possible with `AlertDialog`.

Solution:

Create Custom Dialogs:

```
private void ShowNoti() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ContextThemeWrapper cw = new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this,
                R.style.AppBaseTheme);

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(cw);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Choose delete tasks");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // dialog.dismiss();
                showMsgDialog_new();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void showMsgDialog_new() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_new);
        dialog.setTitle("delete tasks!");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button

        Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        Button cancleBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button12);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        cancleBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```